# Unclear sequence of constructor calls fro two objects

Tags: constructor, output, destructor

Check of when an constructor being called for two different objects. Unexpected constructor call (unclear sequence)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Geeks
{
    public:
    int id;
    
    Geeks()
    {
        cout << "Constructor called for id: " << id <<endl;
    }
    //Definition for Destructor
    ~Geeks()
    {
        cout << "Destructor called for id: " << id <<endl; 
    }
};
  
int main() 
  {
    Geeks obj1;
    obj1.id=7;
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < 5 )
    {
        Geeks obj2;
        obj2.id=i;
        i++;        
    } // Scope for obj2 ends here
  
    return 0;
  } // Scope for obj1 ends here
```

Hello together, i run this snipped of code and interestingly I am getting following output...

**Constructor called for id: 0

Constructor called for id: 1

Destructor called for id: 0

Constructor called for id: 0

Destructor called for id: 1

Constructor called for id: 1

Destructor called for id: 2

Constructor called for id: 2

Destructor called for id: 3

Constructor called for id: 3

Destructor called for id: 4

Destructor called for id: 7**

I dont get why the second output line gives me 1 and not 0 ? I had rather expected that both constructors are being called for two objects with initial id = 0

Thank you